# Python LXML Getting Data from Steam Bundle Page - List out of the index error

Tags: python, xpath, python-requests, lxml, steam

I am working on python program that after it gets **ID of steam bundle** - it returns **the current price**.

Program is using **requests** and **lxml**.

There are two paths for the final price:

1. /html/body/div[1]/div[7]/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[10]/div[3]/div
2. //*[@id="game_area_purchase"]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]

Using example: https://store.steampowered.com/bundle/16140

Here's a code:

```
import requests
import lxml.html
    
#example URL for steam bundle    
URL = "https://store.steampowered.com/bundle/16140"
    
html = requests.get(URL)
doc = lxml.html.fromstring(html.content)
    
#xpath to price location    
price = doc.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[7]/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[10]/div[3]/div/text()')
    
print(price)
```

Program returns this:

```
[]
```

or this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File <path-to-program>, line 9, in <module>
    price = doc.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[7]/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[10]/div[3]/div/text()')[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I get an error for both options.
What should I do to fix it?

Comment: When you request page `requests` returns you not what you expect - it returns you page with Sexual content/Nudity warning. You can try to create `requests.Session` to send several requests within single session. Note that you should send POST-request with your birth date data. Also note that your approach should work well with other pages that don't need age verification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get required page HTML you need to add request with `birthtime` cookie that "tells" server that your age allows you to visit page with sexual/nudity content:

```
import requests
import lxml.html
    
URL = "https://store.steampowered.com/bundle/16140"
session = requests.Session()
r1 = session.get(URL)
r1.cookies['birthtime']='439423201'  # this is date in seconds since "epoch" (January 1, 1970)
r2 = session.get(URL, cookies=r1.cookies)

doc = lxml.html.fromstring(r2.content)
print(doc.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "discount_final_price")]/text()')[0])
```